# Can I still earn accolades without Stella?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

If I don't have Stella (she's not hanging out in front of the Defeated Monsters list anymore), can I still earn Accolades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can still earn **some** Accolades, but others will be awarded after Stella returns.

While she was away, I earned Spelunker and Spunky Spelunker.

Shortly after she returned (and before I had cleared any more Grottoes), I earned Cave Dweller.

Comment: And on subsequent entries into the Battle Records menu (without doing more towards each Accolades count), I earned Cave Dweller, Win-a-Lot Prime, and Churchgoer.

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves: You won't be *awarded* any new Accolades while she's away, but the game is still tracking your status, and you'll get a whole bunch of 'em at once when she comes back.